# Hive: how to compare group membership

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table that has all a list of users that belong to a group. Each user shared a photo with some or all of the users in the group. Sometimes the users may also share photos with users outside the group.

```
table1

group_id   mem_id   shared_mem_id
123        90001    90001
123        90001    90002
123        90001    90003
123        90002    90001
123        90002    90002
123        90003    90002
123        90003    90003
```

I have another table that has the roster of the group.

```
table2

group_id   mem_id 
123        90001    
123        90002    
123        90003
```

I want to check whether each user shared with the entire group or part of the group? What's the most efficient way to do this in Hive?

Initially I tried using full outer join as the following but it did not work because it appended rows from table2 only when the mem_id also existed in shared_mem_id in table1.

```
select
a.*, 
b.mem_id 

from table1 
full outer join table2 on a.group_id = b.group_id and a.shared_member_id = b.mem_id
```

Then I ended up doing a collect_set to put all shared_mem_ids and mem_ids in the same row and do the comparison.  This seems like a lot of work for a simple question.

Expected output:

```
group_id   mem_id    share_status
123        90001     1
123        90002     0
123        90003     0
```

Does anyone have a better way to write the query to get the answer faster? Thank you!

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: I am open to the specific format of the output but I would like to tell, for each mem_id, whether they shared with the everyone in the group or just part of the group. So maybe a 1 or 0 would suffice.

Comment: it would be great if you add a table format for your  expected output

Comment: Added. mem_id 90001 has a 1 because they shared with everyone in the group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hive> select * from test_so_t1;
OK
123     90001   90001
123     90001   90002
123     90001   90003
123     90002   90001
123     90002   90002
123     90003   90002
123     90003   90003

hive> select * from test_so_t2;
OK
123     90001
123     90002
123     90003
Time taken: 0.113 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```

Query -

```
select a1.group_id, a1.mem_id, min(case when b1.shared_mem_id is null then 0 else 1 end) from (select distinct a.group_id, a.mem_id, b.mem_id as shared_mem_id from test_so_t1 a, test_so_t2 b) a1 left outer join test_so_t1 b1 on a1.group_id=b1.group_id and a1.mem_id=b1.mem_id and a1.shared_mem_id=b1.shared_mem_id group by a1.group_id, a1.mem_id;
```

Result

```
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 30 seconds 590 msec
OK
123     90001   1
123     90002   0
123     90003   0
```

Comment: I think the middle join is going to return null, because where ‘b.mem_is is null’ can never be true in that join?

Comment: Sorry my bad, should have checked the data and the query.  Changed the query and added results as well

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```
select group_id,mem_id,case when 
    count(distinct shared_mem_id)=(select count(distinct mem_id) from table2 b where a.group_id=b.group_id) then 1 else 0 end as share_status
from table1 a
group by group_id,mem_id
```

Comment: thanks. this only works when the number of shared users happens to match with the number of users in the group. it's possible that the shared is with someone not in the group and the count would match. that's why i wanted to compare the exact mem_ids. does it make sense what I am asking?